# Bug: beginning of post keeps getting deleted

Tags: support, editor

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861623/text-image-not-converting-to-pdf-file-on-click) seems to have the problem that the beginning of the post is getting deleted on every save. The first two lines should read:

> Hey I'm using `jspdf.debug.js` to convert html to pdf... but when an
>   image is included in the page.. it's not getting converted on first
>   click... please suggest a way..

But even after editing that multiple times the read:

> debug.js` to convert html to pdf... But when an image is included in the page it's not getting converted on first click... please suggest a way.

(as you can see, even the first backtick has been removed).

I've been using Safari on OSX Mavericks (Version 7.0.5 (9537.77.4) to edit that post.

Comment: Just tried with latest Chrome on Windows 8.1 - no repro. What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Added that info to the post.

Comment: Have you seen this with any other post?

Comment: as if all those edits were accepted..

Comment: I think I just had the end of my comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try **NOT** starting the first sentence with "Hey".

I think the first "sentence" (the bit up to the first full stop) is being automatically stripped out by the code that removes things like "Hi" and "Hello" from posts.

Comment: I still think this behavior is more of a bug than a feature if it strips away essential parts of the post.

Comment: @MaxLeske - what's essential about "Hey"? I know the rest of the "sentence" is essential, but that's not the point.

Comment: Relevant MSE implementation post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/213963)

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not against removing "Hey" but against removing "I'm using jspdf.debug.js" which, in my opinion, is an essential part of the post. As your answer suggests, the first full stop marks the end of the deleted portion, but that full stop is part of a file / program name.

Comment: @MaxLeske The problem is knowing where to stop. Deciding where the "real" sentence is hard, so if you've made the decision to remove the "Hi/Hey/Hello/etc." it's simpler to remove the whole sentence even though that might make mistakes like this one.