# Is the "Hi" filter working?

Tags: support, filtering

I've come across 4 to 6 questions that start with "Hi". It's kind of odd since I don't recall encountering that many in the last month.

Most recently, the question is:

- [Convert ImageSource to WriteableBitmap in Metro Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797915/convert-imagesource-to-writeablebitmap-in-metro-windows-8)

But I came across them in the Low Quality and First Post queses, too:

- [Delete simulator safari cookies and caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441687/delete-simulator-safari-cookies-and-caches)
- [Android include xml not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441536/android-include-xml-not-working)
- [jQuery waypoints not working on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445306/jquery-waypoints-not-working-on-localhost)

The jQuery question was just asked, the iOS question was asked two hours ago, and the Android question was asked three hours ago.

Also, when I begin to edit the question, the salutation is not automatically removed.

Is that filter still being used? Is it working as expected?

Comment: Links? Are they new questions or old ones that have just had new answers posted?

Comment: @Chris - I added a few links. I can add more if needed.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with where the first punctuation/new line appears. If you have "Hi, I'm asking..." or "Hi<br>I'm asking..." you can be sure what to remove, but if you have "Hi I'm asking..." where do you stop? Though from this question - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266259/bug-beginning-of-post-keeps-getting-deleted - it would appear that the first "sentence" *was* being removed.

Answer (score 20):

There was a bit of a problem when we rolled out the Genuine StackDeSalutatorSuperDeluxe: it automatically 'de saluted' entire <strike>paragraphs</strike> sentences beginning with "Hi."

All that you've linked match this:

> Hi, I've got this problem with the ointment Apple sent me, I'm not sure where it goes

Instead of:

> Hi
>
> I've got this problem with the ointment Apple sent me, I'm not sure where it goes

I'm ***99.9%*** sure that we won't automatically strip the salutation if we can't clearly match it (and not remove other things too), so you'll see some of these. Because some things are best learned the hard way.

To be quite honest, I find the idea of silently removing bits of text that people submit to be rather wonky, I'd rather do this completely through just-in-time help, but then Jeff appears on my right shoulder and reminds me that *many people simply don't read*.

I'm not entirely sure how we're going to handle this going forward because it does cross paths with the quality project, I'm hoping for consistency, at the least :)

But anyway, there are some instances where it can't be removed safely.

Comment: The name of the filter is funny.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it has to strip out entire paragraphs.  Why can't you just trim out individual words and phrases: "Hi", "Hello", "Hey", etc.?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not entirely sure. I just know it was a problem

Comment: did the filter by chance try to [parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/839601)?

Comment: Why remove/trim anything? Forbid to post in the first place, explaining that fluff is not welcome. That way, you actually teach the user.

Comment: It's good to know other people are having issues with that ointment too.

Comment: Happy to see even someone involved in this isn't super happy with just silently removing text.  I think it's really not the way a UI should be designed :/

Comment: @FooBar: because *Jeff appears on my right shoulder and reminds me that many people simply don't read.* Instead of people complaining because their salutation is gone you'll end up with people complaining because they can't post messages.

Comment: @FooBar Then you'll just see "`Hi` (sorry for code: wouldn't let me submit). I'm having a problem with XYZ..."

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure it's the actual reason, but consider this misspelling (as most of our users are not native speakers): `Hi fi has always been a problem to me - Recently I've bought ....`. Automatically you'd turn the start into "fi" and ruin the understanding. With `Hi<br /><br />fi` there's no question.

Comment: How about instead of some tool-tip that people would (not) read, a 3-seconds animation of drawing a huge red X over a question with highlighted salutation followed by a friendly green V over the same question with the salutation removed?

Comment: @FooBar I would prefer this as well. However, I wouldn't entirely forbid it, but when trying to submit show a big warning and explanation and the user has to actively submit it again. This way we would avoid problems with false positives (e.g. imagine a new superduper framework called _Hi_ and someone wants to ask "Hi is doing something unexpected...")

Comment: Seems it's a *hi-pass filter* now :0

Comment: It's pretty common to see `hi` and `lo` in code. I hope that won't be stripped.

Comment: Hahahaha, now I know why some question I recently saw began with "all, [...]" :D

Comment: Per May 2016, The Hi Filter [still fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37071230/2564301).