# "java script" misspelling - Correct it when typed, ignore for searching on "java"

Tags: feature-request, spelling

Careless authors sometimes misspell `JavaScript` as `Java Script` or `java script` when posting Questions or Answers. These become false-positive hits when searching for `Java`.

Is it possible for the text editor to correct this troublesome misspelling? Or refuse to accept an entry with that word pair?

Can the searching feature be enhanced to not consider "java script" as a match for "java"?

Comment: How about [java -script](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+-script)?

Comment: @rene Nice tip, but I was hoping to put the burden on the computers rather than the humans.

Comment: Sure, but the few automatic filters currently implemented cause more [pr0blams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so) then they [solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269532/is-the-hi-filter-working) so that also explains my down vote.

Comment: Well, the filter wouldn't have to *block*. It would probably be enough to advise: "did you mean javascript?"

Comment: The current generation of developers think only in scripts if you ask me. So Java code becomes "java scripts" as well. I do not support this feature in this day and age.

Comment: I'd strongly prefer that posts get corrected rather than try to automatically filter search results based on misspellings. If a post contains content good enough to turn up in search results, it should be edited into shape.